# how to select or display records based on some query in django's admin

Tags: django

(i'm a django newbie)

We need to delete certain records from a django table (comments).

I prefer to do this from the admin and not directly using the database engine (mysql, btw), because of the naive assumption that it will handle relastionships or software restrictions.

there are hundreds or thousands of records, and the ideal was to put a WHERE query somehow, and select all.

how can I filter the recordset in the admin?

django: latest stable.

thank you

Comment: Do you have access to the site code or just to the admin page?

Comment: i have access to the code, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python script / django console is an option? 
there you could simply

```
Comment.objects.filter(**where_dict).delete()
```

of course not the best to try directly on production environments :)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to use the shell:

```
$ python /path/to/site/manage.py shell
```

Then

```
>>> from comments.models import Comment
>>> Comment.objects.filter(content__icontains='spam').delete()
```